# Plotting Using Nesting Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

My goal is to plot the number of locatable points and their average point as fig2. The number of points is set by the slider and they are locatable. My code with nesting Manipulate is as shown below, but an error-'Argument Null in Null is not a valid LinkObject'-occurred. Where should I fix my code as below?

```
Manipulate[With[{n = n},
  Manipulate[NumberLinePlot[{pts, {Mean[pts]}}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}],
   {pts, RandomReal[{0, 4}, n], Locator, Appearance -> None, 
    LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]], {{n, 2}, 1, 100, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

fig.1)
[image]
[image]

fig.2)
[image]

Comment: do not use nested Manipulates. I do not think this is even allowed in Wolfram demonstration web site. I remember this was one of the rules long time ago.  It is hard enough to get one Manipulate to work right, never mind one inside another :) I never ever had to nest manipulates for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
Manipulate[
  NumberLinePlot[{u[[All, 1]], {Mean[u[[All, 1]]]}}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}],
  {{u, {{0, 0}}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> {1, pointCount}},
  {pointCount, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: MMA 13.3 Unfortunately this does not work. Only 1 point is displayed.

Comment: @DanielHuber It works as expected for me on 13.3. You need to use the slider to increase the number of points and you need to command-click to add new points (or remove points). This seems to match what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: There is only 1 point, I can move the slider and command click to no avail.

Comment: Does a regular click at least move the single point?

Comment: Yes it does. move the point

Comment: I'm on MacOS. I've verified it with 13.3.1 and 13.2.1. This seems very weird.